# JSONDecodeError when parsing JSON

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to parse a JSON file, which consists of multiple tweets streamed using tweepy. When trying to read a JSON file consisting of only one tweet, I can read it no problem. When trying to read a JSON file consisting of multiple tweets, I get an error. I think either I'm missing some type of encoding, or the JSON is formatted incorrectly.

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Repos\Testing\parse_json.py", line 16, in <module>
tweet = json.load(data_file)
File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 299, in load
parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 342, in decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 3 column 1 (char 2753)
```

Here is my parse_json.py code:

```
import json

with open('raw_tweets.json') as data_file:
    tweet = json.load(data_file)

print(f"Created: {tweet['created_at']} \t Tweet: {tweet['text']}  \t Language: {tweet['lang']}")
```

Here is my raw_tweets.json:

```
{"created_at":"Sun Nov 12 16:11:40 +0000 2017","id":929743506096001024,"id_str":"929743506096001024","text":"#Sentiment analysis of The Velveteen Rabbit https:\/\/t.co\/MLSItn74wz #keyphrase #language #nltk #pattern #python","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/www.ajaymatharu.com\/\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTweet Old Post\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":811014723328090112,"id_str":"811014723328090112","name":"Addie","screen_name":"RealThinks_","location":null,"url":"http:\/\/students.washington.edu\/adelak\/","description":"Chemist.  Data scientist.  Dinosaur enthusiast.  Pretty big on the whole \"being nice to people\" thing.","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":439,"friends_count":388,"listed_count":36,"favourites_count":105,"statuses_count":974,"created_at":"Tue Dec 20 01:05:52 +0000 2016","utc_offset":-28800,"time_zone":"Pacific Time (US & Canada)","geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"000000","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1B95E0","profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"000000","profile_text_color":"000000","profile_use_background_image":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/811016747037782017\/V32aJln5_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/811016747037782017\/V32aJln5_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/811014723328090112\/1482462522","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"Sentiment","indices":[0,10]},{"text":"keyphrase","indices":[68,78]},{"text":"language","indices":[79,88]},{"text":"nltk","indices":[89,94]},{"text":"pattern","indices":[95,103]},{"text":"python","indices":[104,111]}],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/MLSItn74wz","expanded_url":"http:\/\/students.washington.edu\/adelak\/2016\/12\/?p=18","display_url":"students.washington.edu\/adelak\/2016\/12\u2026","indices":[44,67]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1510503100309"}

{"created_at":"Sun Nov 12 16:11:53 +0000 2017","id":929743561217671168,"id_str":"929743561217671168","text":"RT @kdnuggets: Tips for Getting Started with Text Mining in #rstats and #Python https:\/\/t.co\/dWLXBTu7Ap https:\/\/t.co\/XRyRE9lej8","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/android\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for Android\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":219290077,"id_str":"219290077","name":"Lilia Quituisaca S","screen_name":"LiliaQuituisaca","location":"Guasuntos","url":"http:\/\/liliaquituisaca-poesias.blogspot.com\/","description":"Ingeniera Inform\u00e1tica. OpenSource. JAVA. R-project. Weka. Datamining. Simulaci\u00f3n. Escribo y declamo poes\u00eda -destino,sin miedo- El arte perfecciona los sentidos.","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":1125,"friends_count":2308,"listed_count":631,"favourites_count":1228,"statuses_count":26375,"created_at":"Wed Nov 24 13:10:16 +0000 2010","utc_offset":-18000,"time_zone":"Quito","geo_enabled":true,"lang":"es","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000032598931\/b322745f32a73f540fa42b54c27ac75a.jpeg","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000032598931\/b322745f32a73f540fa42b54c27ac75a.jpeg","profile_background_tile":true,"profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/780178494466711552\/9ONWkWlC_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/780178494466711552\/9ONWkWlC_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/219290077\/1357069442","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweeted_status":{"created_at":"Sun Nov 12 15:42:02 +0000 2017","id":929736050687332354,"id_str":"929736050687332354","text":"Tips for Getting Started with Text Mining in #rstats and #Python https:\/\/t.co\/dWLXBTu7Ap https:\/\/t.co\/XRyRE9lej8","display_text_range":[0,88],"source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/bufferapp.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eBuffer\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":20167623,"id_str":"20167623","name":"KDnuggets","screen_name":"kdnuggets","location":"Brookline, MA, USA","url":"https:\/\/www.kdnuggets.com\/","description":"Covering #AI, #Analytics, #BigData, #DataMining, #DataScience #MachineLearning, #DeepLearning.  Founded by Gregory Piatetsky-Shapiro.","translator_type":"regular","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":98870,"friends_count":400,"listed_count":5477,"favourites_count":448,"statuses_count":42854,"created_at":"Thu Feb 05 17:37:26 +0000 2009","utc_offset":-18000,"time_zone":"Eastern Time (US & Canada)","geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"0099B9","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000050609482\/c32d3d654da4eb7c0518e7bba2609522.jpeg","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000050609482\/c32d3d654da4eb7c0518e7bba2609522.jpeg","profile_background_tile":true,"profile_link_color":"0099B9","profile_sidebar_border_color":"5ED4DC","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"95E8EC","profile_text_color":"3C3940","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/795788806008041473\/0nTPcRja_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/795788806008041473\/0nTPcRja_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/20167623\/1476546748","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":9,"favorite_count":6,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"rstats","indices":[45,52]},{"text":"Python","indices":[57,64]}],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/dWLXBTu7Ap","expanded_url":"https:\/\/buff.ly\/2zyOtix","display_url":"buff.ly\/2zyOtix","indices":[65,88]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[],"media":[{"id":929736048183336960,"id_str":"929736048183336960","indices":[89,112],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/DOcWAobX4AAf9ze.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/DOcWAobX4AAf9ze.jpg","url":"https:\/\/t.co\/XRyRE9lej8","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/XRyRE9lej8","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/kdnuggets\/status\/929736050687332354\/photo\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"large":{"w":800,"h":338,"resize":"fit"},"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"medium":{"w":800,"h":338,"resize":"fit"},"small":{"w":680,"h":287,"resize":"fit"}}}]},"extended_entities":{"media":[{"id":929736048183336960,"id_str":"929736048183336960","indices":[89,112],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/DOcWAobX4AAf9ze.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/DOcWAobX4AAf9ze.jpg","url":"https:\/\/t.co\/XRyRE9lej8","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/XRyRE9lej8","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/kdnuggets\/status\/929736050687332354\/photo\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"large":{"w":800,"h":338,"resize":"fit"},"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"medium":{"w":800,"h":338,"resize":"fit"},"small":{"w":680,"h":287,"resize":"fit"}}}]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en"},"is_quote_status":false,"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"rstats","indices":[60,67]},{"text":"Python","indices":[72,79]}],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/dWLXBTu7Ap","expanded_url":"https:\/\/buff.ly\/2zyOtix","display_url":"buff.ly\/2zyOtix","indices":[80,103]}],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"kdnuggets","name":"KDnuggets","id":20167623,"id_str":"20167623","indices":[3,13]}],"symbols":[],"media":[{"id":929736048183336960,"id_str":"929736048183336960","indices":[104,127],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/DOcWAobX4AAf9ze.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/DOcWAobX4AAf9ze.jpg","url":"https:\/\/t.co\/XRyRE9lej8","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/XRyRE9lej8","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/kdnuggets\/status\/929736050687332354\/photo\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"large":{"w":800,"h":338,"resize":"fit"},"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"medium":{"w":800,"h":338,"resize":"fit"},"small":{"w":680,"h":287,"resize":"fit"}},"source_status_id":929736050687332354,"source_status_id_str":"929736050687332354","source_user_id":20167623,"source_user_id_str":"20167623"}]},"extended_entities":{"media":[{"id":929736048183336960,"id_str":"929736048183336960","indices":[104,127],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/DOcWAobX4AAf9ze.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/DOcWAobX4AAf9ze.jpg","url":"https:\/\/t.co\/XRyRE9lej8","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/XRyRE9lej8","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/kdnuggets\/status\/929736050687332354\/photo\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"large":{"w":800,"h":338,"resize":"fit"},"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"medium":{"w":800,"h":338,"resize":"fit"},"small":{"w":680,"h":287,"resize":"fit"}},"source_status_id":929736050687332354,"source_status_id_str":"929736050687332354","source_user_id":20167623,"source_user_id_str":"20167623"}]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1510503113451"}
```

Here is the code for my listener:

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import json

consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)


class MyListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            with open('raw_tweets.json', 'a') as f:
                f.write(data)
                print("Tweet")
                return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    twitter_stream = Stream(auth, MyListener())
    print("Streaming Tweets...")
    twitter_stream.filter(track=['#python'], languages=['en'])
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON. At least, the `json` module won't read it. You need to put the individual tweet objects into a list.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from your JSON file, it should be within an array like this:

```
[{'property1':'value1', 'property2':'value2'},{'property1':'value1', 'property2':'value2'}]
```

This is how your JSON file should look like:

```
[{
    "created_at": "Sun Nov 12 16:11:40 +0000 2017",
    "id": 929743506096001024,
    "id_str": "929743506096001024",
    "text": "#Sentiment analysis of The Velveteen Rabbit https:\/\/t.co\/MLSItn74wz #keyphrase #language #nltk #pattern #python",
    "source": "\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/www.ajaymatharu.com\/\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTweet Old Post\u003c\/a\u003e",
    "truncated": false,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "user": {
        "id": 811014723328090112,
        "id_str": "811014723328090112",
        "name": "Addie",
        "screen_name": "RealThinks_",
        "location": null,
        "url": "http:\/\/students.washington.edu\/adelak\/",
        "description": "Chemist.  Data scientist.  Dinosaur enthusiast.  Pretty big on the whole \"being nice to people\" thing.",
        "translator_type": "none",
        "protected": false,
        "verified": false,
        "followers_count": 439,
        "friends_count": 388,
        "listed_count": 36,
        "favourites_count": 105,
        "statuses_count": 974,
        "created_at": "Tue Dec 20 01:05:52 +0000 2016",
        "utc_offset": -28800,
        "time_zone": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
        "geo_enabled": false,
        "lang": "en",
        "contributors_enabled": false,
        "is_translator": false,
        "profile_background_color": "000000",
        "profile_background_image_url": "http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png",
        "profile_background_image_url_https": "https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png",
        "profile_background_tile": false,
        "profile_link_color": "1B95E0",
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "000000",
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "000000",
        "profile_text_color": "000000",
        "profile_use_background_image": false,
        "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/811016747037782017\/V32aJln5_normal.jpg",
        "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/811016747037782017\/V32aJln5_normal.jpg",
        "profile_banner_url": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/811014723328090112\/1482462522",
        "default_profile": false,
        "default_profile_image": false,
        "following": null,
        "follow_request_sent": null,
        "notifications": null
    },
    "geo": null,
    "coordinates": null,
    "place": null,
    "contributors": null,
    "is_quote_status": false,
    "quote_count": 0,
    "reply_count": 0,
    "retweet_count": 0,
    "favorite_count": 0,
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [{
            "text": "Sentiment",
            "indices": [0, 10]
        }, {
            "text": "keyphrase",
            "indices": [68, 78]
        }, {
            "text": "language",
            "indices": [79, 88]
        }, {
            "text": "nltk",
            "indices": [89, 94]
        }, {
            "text": "pattern",
            "indices": [95, 103]
        }, {
            "text": "python",
            "indices": [104, 111]
        }],
        "urls": [{
            "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/MLSItn74wz",
            "expanded_url": "http:\/\/students.washington.edu\/adelak\/2016\/12\/?p=18",
            "display_url": "students.washington.edu\/adelak\/2016\/12\u2026",
            "indices": [44, 67]
        }],
        "user_mentions": [],
        "symbols": []
    },
    "favorited": false,
    "retweeted": false,
    "possibly_sensitive": false,
    "filter_level": "low",
    "lang": "en",
    "timestamp_ms": "1510503100309"
}, {
    "created_at": "Sun Nov 12 16:11:53 +0000 2017",
    "id": 929743561217671168,
    "id_str": "929743561217671168",
    "text": "RT @kdnuggets: Tips for Getting Started with Text Mining in #rstats and #Python https:\/\/t.co\/dWLXBTu7Ap https:\/\/t.co\/XRyRE9lej8",
    "source": "\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/android\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for Android\u003c\/a\u003e",
    "truncated": false,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "user": {
        "id": 219290077,
        "id_str": "219290077",
        "name": "Lilia Quituisaca S",
        "screen_name": "LiliaQuituisaca",
        "location": "Guasuntos",
        "url": "http:\/\/liliaquituisaca-poesias.blogspot.com\/",
        "description": "Ingeniera Inform\u00e1tica. OpenSource. JAVA. R-project. Weka. Datamining. Simulaci\u00f3n. Escribo y declamo poes\u00eda -destino,sin miedo- El arte perfecciona los sentidos.",
        "translator_type": "none",
        "protected": false,
        "verified": false,
        "followers_count": 1125,
        "friends_count": 2308,
        "listed_count": 631,
        "favourites_count": 1228,
        "statuses_count": 26375,
        "created_at": "Wed Nov 24 13:10:16 +0000 2010",
        "utc_offset": -18000,
        "time_zone": "Quito",
        "geo_enabled": true,
        "lang": "es",
        "contributors_enabled": false,
        "is_translator": false,
        "profile_background_color": "C0DEED",
        "profile_background_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000032598931\/b322745f32a73f540fa42b54c27ac75a.jpeg",
        "profile_background_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000032598931\/b322745f32a73f540fa42b54c27ac75a.jpeg",
        "profile_background_tile": true,
        "profile_link_color": "0084B4",
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "FFFFFF",
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
        "profile_text_color": "333333",
        "profile_use_background_image": true,
        "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/780178494466711552\/9ONWkWlC_normal.jpg",
        "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/780178494466711552\/9ONWkWlC_normal.jpg",
        "profile_banner_url": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/219290077\/1357069442",
        "default_profile": false,
        "default_profile_image": false,
        "following": null,
        "follow_request_sent": null,
        "notifications": null
    },
    "geo": null,
    "coordinates": null,
    "place": null,
    "contributors": null,
    "retweeted_status": {
        "created_at": "Sun Nov 12 15:42:02 +0000 2017",
        "id": 929736050687332354,
        "id_str": "929736050687332354",
        "text": "Tips for Getting Started with Text Mining in #rstats and #Python https:\/\/t.co\/dWLXBTu7Ap https:\/\/t.co\/XRyRE9lej8",
        "display_text_range": [0, 88],
        "source": "\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/bufferapp.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eBuffer\u003c\/a\u003e",
        "truncated": false,
        "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
        "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
        "user": {
            "id": 20167623,
            "id_str": "20167623",
            "name": "KDnuggets",
            "screen_name": "kdnuggets",
            "location": "Brookline, MA, USA",
            "url": "https:\/\/www.kdnuggets.com\/",
            "description": "Covering #AI, #Analytics, #BigData, #DataMining, #DataScience #MachineLearning, #DeepLearning.  Founded by Gregory Piatetsky-Shapiro.",
            "translator_type": "regular",
            "protected": false,
            "verified": false,
            "followers_count": 98870,
            "friends_count": 400,
            "listed_count": 5477,
            "favourites_count": 448,
            "statuses_count": 42854,
            "created_at": "Thu Feb 05 17:37:26 +0000 2009",
            "utc_offset": -18000,
            "time_zone": "Eastern Time (US & Canada)",
            "geo_enabled": false,
            "lang": "en",
            "contributors_enabled": false,
            "is_translator": false,
            "profile_background_color": "0099B9",
            "profile_background_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000050609482\/c32d3d654da4eb7c0518e7bba2609522.jpeg",
            "profile_background_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000050609482\/c32d3d654da4eb7c0518e7bba2609522.jpeg",
            "profile_background_tile": true,
            "profile_link_color": "0099B9",
            "profile_sidebar_border_color": "5ED4DC",
            "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "95E8EC",
            "profile_text_color": "3C3940",
            "profile_use_background_image": true,
            "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/795788806008041473\/0nTPcRja_normal.jpg",
            "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/795788806008041473\/0nTPcRja_normal.jpg",
            "profile_banner_url": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/20167623\/1476546748",
            "default_profile": false,
            "default_profile_image": false,
            "following": null,
            "follow_request_sent": null,
            "notifications": null
        },
        "geo": null,
        "coordinates": null,
        "place": null,
        "contributors": null,
        "is_quote_status": false,
        "quote_count": 0,
        "reply_count": 0,
        "retweet_count": 9,
        "favorite_count": 6,
        "entities": {
            "hashtags": [{
                "text": "rstats",
                "indices": [45, 52]
            }, {
                "text": "Python",
                "indices": [57, 64]
            }],
            "urls": [{
                "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/dWLXBTu7Ap",
                "expanded_url": "https:\/\/buff.ly\/2zyOtix",
                "display_url": "buff.ly\/2zyOtix",
                "indices": [65, 88]
            }],
            "user_mentions": [],
            "symbols": [],
            "media": [{
                "id": 929736048183336960,
                "id_str": "929736048183336960",
                "indices": [89, 112],
                "media_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/DOcWAobX4AAf9ze.jpg",
                "media_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/DOcWAobX4AAf9ze.jpg",
                "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/XRyRE9lej8",
                "display_url": "pic.twitter.com\/XRyRE9lej8",
                "expanded_url": "https:\/\/twitter.com\/kdnuggets\/status\/929736050687332354\/photo\/1",
                "type": "photo",
                "sizes": {
                    "large": {
                        "w": 800,
                        "h": 338,
                        "resize": "fit"
                    },
                    "thumb": {
                        "w": 150,
                        "h": 150,
                        "resize": "crop"
                    },
                    "medium": {
                        "w": 800,
                        "h": 338,
                        "resize": "fit"
                    },
                    "small": {
                        "w": 680,
                        "h": 287,
                        "resize": "fit"
                    }
                }
            }]
        },
        "extended_entities": {
            "media": [{
                "id": 929736048183336960,
                "id_str": "929736048183336960",
                "indices": [89, 112],
                "media_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/DOcWAobX4AAf9ze.jpg",
                "media_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/DOcWAobX4AAf9ze.jpg",
                "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/XRyRE9lej8",
                "display_url": "pic.twitter.com\/XRyRE9lej8",
                "expanded_url": "https:\/\/twitter.com\/kdnuggets\/status\/929736050687332354\/photo\/1",
                "type": "photo",
                "sizes": {
                    "large": {
                        "w": 800,
                        "h": 338,
                        "resize": "fit"
                    },
                    "thumb": {
                        "w": 150,
                        "h": 150,
                        "resize": "crop"
                    },
                    "medium": {
                        "w": 800,
                        "h": 338,
                        "resize": "fit"
                    },
                    "small": {
                        "w": 680,
                        "h": 287,
                        "resize": "fit"
                    }
                }
            }]
        },
        "favorited": false,
        "retweeted": false,
        "possibly_sensitive": false,
        "filter_level": "low",
        "lang": "en"
    },
    "is_quote_status": false,
    "quote_count": 0,
    "reply_count": 0,
    "retweet_count": 0,
    "favorite_count": 0,
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [{
            "text": "rstats",
            "indices": [60, 67]
        }, {
            "text": "Python",
            "indices": [72, 79]
        }],
        "urls": [{
            "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/dWLXBTu7Ap",
            "expanded_url": "https:\/\/buff.ly\/2zyOtix",
            "display_url": "buff.ly\/2zyOtix",
            "indices": [80, 103]
        }],
        "user_mentions": [{
            "screen_name": "kdnuggets",
            "name": "KDnuggets",
            "id": 20167623,
            "id_str": "20167623",
            "indices": [3, 13]
        }],
        "symbols": [],
        "media": [{
            "id": 929736048183336960,
            "id_str": "929736048183336960",
            "indices": [104, 127],
            "media_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/DOcWAobX4AAf9ze.jpg",
            "media_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/DOcWAobX4AAf9ze.jpg",
            "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/XRyRE9lej8",
            "display_url": "pic.twitter.com\/XRyRE9lej8",
            "expanded_url": "https:\/\/twitter.com\/kdnuggets\/status\/929736050687332354\/photo\/1",
            "type": "photo",
            "sizes": {
                "large": {
                    "w": 800,
                    "h": 338,
                    "resize": "fit"
                },
                "thumb": {
                    "w": 150,
                    "h": 150,
                    "resize": "crop"
                },
                "medium": {
                    "w": 800,
                    "h": 338,
                    "resize": "fit"
                },
                "small": {
                    "w": 680,
                    "h": 287,
                    "resize": "fit"
                }
            },
            "source_status_id": 929736050687332354,
            "source_status_id_str": "929736050687332354",
            "source_user_id": 20167623,
            "source_user_id_str": "20167623"
        }]
    },
    "extended_entities": {
        "media": [{
            "id": 929736048183336960,
            "id_str": "929736048183336960",
            "indices": [104, 127],
            "media_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/DOcWAobX4AAf9ze.jpg",
            "media_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/DOcWAobX4AAf9ze.jpg",
            "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/XRyRE9lej8",
            "display_url": "pic.twitter.com\/XRyRE9lej8",
            "expanded_url": "https:\/\/twitter.com\/kdnuggets\/status\/929736050687332354\/photo\/1",
            "type": "photo",
            "sizes": {
                "large": {
                    "w": 800,
                    "h": 338,
                    "resize": "fit"
                },
                "thumb": {
                    "w": 150,
                    "h": 150,
                    "resize": "crop"
                },
                "medium": {
                    "w": 800,
                    "h": 338,
                    "resize": "fit"
                },
                "small": {
                    "w": 680,
                    "h": 287,
                    "resize": "fit"
                }
            },
            "source_status_id": 929736050687332354,
            "source_status_id_str": "929736050687332354",
            "source_user_id": 20167623,
            "source_user_id_str": "20167623"
        }]
    },
    "favorited": false,
    "retweeted": false,
    "possibly_sensitive": false,
    "filter_level": "low",
    "lang": "en",
    "timestamp_ms": "1510503113451"
}]
```

There are some tools online that [validate JSONS](https://jsonlint.com/) otherwise some IDEs can also do that too.

Comment: So is there a problem with the "MyListener" class if it's not correctly exporting JSON?

Comment: Yes that's exact, you need to output your JSON as I've written on my answer. Don't mind the formatting, you just need to make sure you wrap you export with squared brackets and that you separate each object (the curly brackets {} ) with comas except the last object. Just like I've written above :)